# Unable to start puppetmaster on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, puppet, centos6, puppetmaster

I installed puppet 2.6.12 on CentOS 6. When I try to start the puppetmaster service using the command `service puppetmaster start` I get the error:

```
Starting puppetmaster: /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/ssl_file.rb:142:in open: Permission denied - /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca (Errno::EACCES).
```

If I do `sudo service puppetmaster start` I get the error

```
 Starting puppetmaster: Could not prepare for execution: Could not find a default provider for user
```

I have ruby 1.8.7,ruby-libs and ruby-shadow installed. How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Do you have SELinux installed and active?

Comment: I had done a fresh install of CentOS6. Dont have any idea about SELinux. Is that the cause of the problem ?

Comment: Run `getenforce` to check the SELinux status on the box. I believe default is to enable it.

Comment: When i run the command `getenforce` it shows `Enforcing`. Does that mean its already enabled ?.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable SELinux or at least put it into Permissive mode and see if the issue resolves. To do this just edit the `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` file and change the value of `SELINUX` as directed in the file.

If this solves the problem then SELinux is interfering with Puppet's operation and you can either keep it disabled/permissive if having SELinux enabled is not required or would require determining why SELinux is having problems. [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/30796/reasons-to-disable-enable-selinux) question related as to whether or not SELinux should be enabled or disabled.

Comment: Terrible advice. Simply to say 'disable selinux' does not solve anyone's problem.

Comment: Try re-reading the answer Mike as I wasn't simply saying to disable selinux but mark it to 'Permissive' which allows the actions to take place but logs the action as a means of troubleshooting to see if selinux is the cause for the failure.